# IBM watson internet of things platform: Connecting using client certs & mosquitto client

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt, mosquitto, watson-iot

I get below error while trying  to connect to IBM Watson internet of things platform using client certs & mosquitto client. The same certs work fine with node.js client hence I know certs are fine, just some config in mosquitto client which is erroneous.

```
mosquitto_sub -h dumorg.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com -p 8883 --capath ./certs/ -t "iot-2/type/dumtype/id/dumid/cmd/+/fmt/json" -v  -i g:dumorg:dumtype:dummid --cert ./client.crt --key ./client.key
```

Connection Refused: not authorised.

When I try to perform same connection using auth-token it goes through fine

```
$ mosquitto_sub -h dumorg.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com -p 8883 --capath ./certs/ -t "iot-2/type/dumtype/id/dumid/cmd/+/fmt/json" -v  -i g:dumorg:dumtype:dumid -P dumpassword -u use-token-auth
```

I am also able to successfully connect using certs through another client. I know the certs are fine, and mosquitto command works with auth token. hence issue is some missing/incorrect config in mosquitto due to which IoT platform doesn't like certs used to connect with mosquitto?

Answer (score 1):

Seems mosquitto does not support SNI which is required to connect to MQTT broker on IBM cloud. Manually inserting this patch https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/pull/626 and building mosquitto resolved issue. Hope this is merged in main branch in near future.